# ASCC for PID - quick proof explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

There is an extremely short and good proof on wikipedia https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Principal_Ideal_Domain_fulfills_Ascending_Chain_Condition

Now what confuses me is that what motivates one to start with the union of all ideals in the chain? This feels like some background work was done much like the proofs you do in analysis.

Comment: That's not Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an ascending chain of sets in general, the union is the most natural "limit" of that chain (just as the intersection is the most natural limit of a descending chain of sets). We want to know whether the chain ever stops growing, so examining whether its "limit" is equal to one of the links in the chain is the natural way to do that.

Comment: Ahhh I swear I've seen this same analogy in analysis regarding your limit answer. I swear it was briefly talked over in measure theory

Comment: I am guessing it is because the union is supposedly the "biggest" set right? Actually that doesn't explain why we are taking the lower sets...in the union...

Comment: The union is actually the smallest set that contains them all. But it could be seen as the largest set in the chain, although we don't know beforehand that there _is_ a largest set. It's kind of like how $\sup$ works on the real number line. Morally, it's the largest element of a set, but a set might not have a largest element, so instead it's defined as the smallest element that is larger than all of the elements of the set.

Comment: Right but what is strange to me is that we are taking unions of smaller sets as well. Example, $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset I_3 \subset \dots$. Why would we look at $I = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \dots$, even though (say looking at the initial terms) $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset I_1 \cup I_2 \subset I_2$ instead of looking at a generic "largest" set $I_\sup$

Comment: @Hawk I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you asking why we don't look at, say, $\bigcup_{i = 500}^\infty I_i$? That's because that's the same thing as the original union. Are you asking why we go infinitely far out instead of stopping somewhere out in the sequence and look at things there? That's because we don't know (yet) that the chain will stop, and we certainly don't know _where_ it will stop. Going infinitely far out is sufficient, and simpler than trying to pinpoint some exact stopping criterion.

Comment: Nah I am just wondering why we care about the lower $I_is$ in the union, hence its construction. For example, if $I_1 \subset I_2$, why consider $I_1 \cup I_2$ when $I_1 \cup I_2 = I_2$?

Comment: No reason except legibility. For instance, when asking whether the sum $\sum_{i  = 1}^\infty \frac 1{i^2}$ converges, we usually still start at $i = 1$, even though we could start the sequence anywhere we like. We have to start _somewhere_, and that might as well be at the beginning. It takes a smidgen less mental gymnastics from the reader if he doesn't have to worry about things like "why exactly do you choose to start at term $1\,309\,632$?"